# Firebase query returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to make a query to get data from my database (Firebase), I was trying to fetch all the information from the array, inside the array there are only user ids, according to these ids, I am fetching the information of the users, the problem is that it returns "undefined" in each query that I do, this is my code:

```
const loadInformation = async () => {
        const data = await db.collection('channels').doc(id).get();
        setInformation(data.data());
        const users = await Promise.all(
            data.data().users.map((user) => {
                db.collection('user').doc(user).get();
                /* db.collection('user').where("userId", "==", user).onSnapshot(snap => {
                    setAllUsers(snap.docs.map(doc => ({
                        id: doc.id,
                        data: doc.data()
                    })))
                }) */
            })
        )
        setAllUsers(users)
    }
```

In the first line I am getting the data from the channel and then I am trying to get the data from the users according to the result of the first request.

On the first request, it works fine, and in the loop (map), the user ids work normally (I did a console.log(), and it works).

this is the model of my database:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not returning anything from the innermost closure, you end up with an empty array in your call to `Promise.all()`. Putting `return` at the start of the line with the `get()` call should fix that.

Comment: the information appears correctly, but I try to access the data with allUsers.data(), but it doesn't work I get the message allUsers.data is not a function, I also tried with the snapshop, like the second example putting the return, but in this one it returns an array of functions

Comment: `users` is going to be an array of `DocumentSnapshot` objects, so you'll need to loop over them and call `data()` in each individually. If you can't get it to work based on that, I recommend posting a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) now that the promise handling is fixed.